# angular broadcast from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, broadcast, angular-ng-if

I am trying to broadcast from one directive (claim-points) to another directive (banner-points) on the click of the Claim Points button.

```
<button name="button" claim-points>Claim Points</button>
```

I'd like to hide this "Banner Button" element until the broadcast is sent from claim-points directive to the banner-points directive:

```
<div name="bannerBtn" banner-points ng-if="isVisible">html from banner-points directive displayed here</div>
```

So, on Claim Points button click, it's getting and looping through some data... if it finds a match, it broadcasts to `showbanner`:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('claimPoints', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    $http.get('/testJSON/points.json').success(function(data) {
                            var found = false;
                            angular.forEach(data.data, function(v, k) {
                                if (!found) {
                                    if (v.award_name === attr.award) {
                                        found = true;
                                        $rootScope.$broadcast('showbanner', v.points);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

The broadcast should be sent to `scope.$on('showbanner`, ...`here and set the "Banner Button" attribute`isVisible`to true... which should trigger the`ng-if` on the button.

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('bannerPoints', function () {
        return {
            restrict: '',
            templateUrl: '<div>some html I want to display',
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                attr.isVisible = false;
                scope.$on('showbanner', function(e, b) {
                    attr.isVisible = true;
                });
            }
        };
});
```

The broadcast is not happening.

Comment: le is it possible to make things on jsfidle ?

Comment: is this directive is used multiple times on single html?

Comment: @pankajparkar no it's just used once

Comment: did you face any error on console...it's better you jsfiddle it

Comment: @Growler is `showbanner` is listened form many places or only from directive?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create `bannerPoints` which will have `$on` listener, as you directive is not creating isolated scope, you need to only pass `isVisible` scope variable name to `claimPoints` directive then instead of broadcasting you could directly use scope[attrs.isVisible] & make it true so the `ng-if="isVisible"` will gets satisfied and that button will get shown.

**Markup**

```
<button name="button" claim-points is-visible="isVisible">Claim Points</button>

<button name="bannerBtn" ng-if="isVisible">
    <div>some html I want to display></div>
</button>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('claimPoints', ['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        $http.get('/testJSON/points.json').success(function(data) {
          var found = false;
          angular.forEach(data.data, function(v, k) {
            if (!found) {
              if (v.award_name === attr.award) {
                found = true;
                //this will set isVisible scope to true
                scope[attrs.isVisible] = true;
              }
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: thanks for this. The point of the second bannerPoints directive is that it will load an HTML template with all sorts of things, hence the need for the broadcast.

Comment: @Growler I didn't saw that in your current directive.. could explain more on  what sort of things? & which template you are going to load..in which place?

Comment: sorry about that. Once the Claim Points button is clicked, the broadcast is sent, which will set the the `bannerPoints` directive to be visible. This should display a template with some html/images, etc... see above edit

Comment: @Growler is that html you are going to load is static or depends on some condition it will changed?

Comment: it's going to be static. I'm just passing through some data

Comment: @Growler then why don;t you think to put template in button itself like `<button name="bannerBtn" ng-if="isVisible"><div>some html I want to display></div></button>` as it is gonna show the div only when `claimPoints` button gets clicked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81032/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-growler).